# Scenario Analysis - Real life application

Tags: risk-management, statistical-finance, scenario-analysis

Given a portfolio consists of Stock = usd 40, Bond = usd 40, commodity =usd 20.
Also given the correlation between these assets.

Scenario 1 : stock down by 30%

When performing scenario analysis, do we usually take correlation into account?
or just do it this way:

Stock= 40*0.7=28
Bond= 40
Commodity= 20

Thus portfolio value becomes usd 88.

Is this the correct way to do scenario analysis?

Comment: What is the correlation in your example?

Comment: Equities and Comm , +0.25          Equities and Bonds, 0.5             Bonds and Comm,-0.2

Comment: Were the bond and commodity markets closed on the day of your analysis? If so, your portfolio value seems fine, if not, it appears you are missing some data :)

Comment: What does that mean? Can I just shock the stock as above or what you would suggest? Yes all are historical data already.

Comment: You can analyze a scenario in that way if you like.  In doing so though you are throwing your correlations out the window.  I didn't realize your goal was to shock a single asset.

Comment: hi amdopt, how would suggest to include correlation in. let's say stock down by 30%. how to use correlation to calculate bond and commodity values? if Corr(Stock, bond)=0.6, corr(stock, comm)=0.3?

Comment: and also given the covariance of three terms.